# Extracting Json from xml text file in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, xml, swift, parsing

i have to extract and parse json from a text file, i know how to parse json but i'm just unable to extract it correctly from xml format. this is my xml which contains json.

```
<Data>
<Persons>[{"ID":"2","Name":"Catagory 1"},{"ID":"3","Name":"Catagory 2”</Persons>
<class>[{"ID":"3","Name":"WEAVING”}]</class>
</Data>
```

what i want is to get json sepratly with its tags, like for example.

```
"Persons":"[{"ID":"2","Name":"Catagory 1"},{"ID":"3","Name":"Catagory 2”}]"
```

Comment: Use xml parser to parse the xml you got. There is support for xml parsing in iOS and Swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser

Comment: @firstinq can you elaborate with a code? i'm a bit new to swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the sample code for parsing xml below:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var parser:XMLParser?
    var foundChars: String = ""
    var personsStr: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseXML()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func parseXML() {
        let str: NSString = "<Data><Persons>[{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Catagory 1\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"Catagory 2\"}]</Persons><class>[{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"WEAVING\"}]</class></Data>"
        if let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            parser = XMLParser.init(data: data)
            parser!.delegate = self
            parser!.parse()
        }

    }
}
extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {
    public func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        debugPrint("Person str is:: " + self.personsStr)
        //TODO: You have to build your json object from the PersonStr now
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        self.foundChars = self.foundChars + string
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        debugPrint("end element::" + elementName)
        if (elementName == "Persons") {
            self.personsStr = self.foundChars
        }
        self.foundChars = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it, Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (XML -> JSON).